# How to reset a password (or unlock user) in Zenoss using zendmd? (Usual methods don't work)

Tags: zenoss

I'm new to Zenoss and hired as a System Administrator somewhere that has lost all of their credentials to access Zenoss Control Center WebUI!
Now I've been assigned to find a way to reset admin (or any other user) password. I've checked the web thoroughly and came across zendmd, a python shell connected to Zenoss database. Using this [link](http://wiki.zenoss.org/Reset_Admin_Password) I tried to set the new password, but though it does not throw any errors, I still cannot login with the new credentials I've set.
Also I tried using `zenpass` which is a small script to set the new admin password, but still it seems that it has no effect.
I am familiar with python (fortunately) and I'm trying to understand how I can manipulate database to be able to login. But as this is a OO database and not a relational one, I cannot query it directy. So far, my attemps on fixing the issue have been unsuccessful. Part of it is because there are no documentation related to zendmd objects and classes, and I have to read developer comments to find out what is going on.

Is there any way to reset this? or at least find out what is going on here? I also suspect that the accounts are locked, but I've had no luck finding a way to check this.

**New findings**

I was able to send a reset password email using the following method in zendmd:

```
dmd.ZenUsers.user01.manage_resetPassword()
```

The password in the mail does not work. I guess my problem is not the password, but some other issue with the login...but no idea of what it can be. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some research I found out that I was trying to log in into a wrong login interface! The Control Center is different from Zenoss WebUI (rookie mistake) and now it is OK.

All of the methods with zendmd work perfectly. Actually, this helped me learn a bit of zenoss python shell, which would definitely be useful in close future.